# How to make a gif out of subplot?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using this code from matplotlib website to generate gif through list of images.
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/dynamic_image2.html

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to make it work if I have subplot with two axes inside it. Thus, it is as if I have two images, which one should I append to the list?

EDIT: sample code:

```
ims = []
for i in range(60):
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the page you linked](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/dynamic_image2.html), the array of artists passed to `ArtistAnimation` is a list of lists, each element of the list corresponds to one frame, where all the elements of the "inner" lists are updated.

Therefore

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
# ims is a list of lists, each row is a list of artists to draw in the
# current frame; here we are just animating one artist, the image, in
# each frame
ims = []
for i in range(60):
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im1 = ax1.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)
    im2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.random(size=(100,120)))
    ims.append([im1,im2])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)
```

[image]